# when use 2 network card

Tags: networking, routes, addition

I need to use 2 network card

192.168.2.12
and 
192.168.3.16

every thing look fine  .. shared folder and ping test to 192.168.2.2 and ping to 192.168.3.39

but only one thing not work 
SQL query program (C# program)
the program will query data from 192.168.2.2 (SQL)
if i connect two lan card it can not work,
but if i connect only 192.168.2.12 card and disable 192.168.3.16
it work !!  (after that if i not close the program and plug in cable 192.168.3.16 it still work)

what should i do ? 
where to check or where to correct ?

Please help Me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data you have given, the problem you are facing should not have any dependency on the two network cards. I assume, you are trying to connect to your sql server which is x.x.2.2 and you have a network card with x.x.2.12/24 IP. This makes, your server has L2 connectivity with your host, so there is no reason it shouldn't work. Also, your ping is working with both network cards connected?

You can try few things to debug the problem.

1. Confirm there is no stray configuration exists in the system which sends all the pkts to the .3 subnet. Something like a default route "ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 x.x.3.x". If yes, remove it.
2. Since its L2 connected, you should see the ARP getting resolved. Check if the ARP for the .2.2 server is resolved.
3. If not, Start a packet capture tool (something like wireshark, ethereal, tcpdump) on .2 interface and then .3 interface and confirm where you are seeing the ARP pacckets and data packets. You should see them on .2 interface. Otherwise, you have a bad configuration. Somewhere.

Post the outputs and more observation so that we can help you better.

Comment: Thank for answer " there is 0.0.0.0 default route as you said .
after delete that route ,Do i need to manualy add route for it interface.

Comment: You don't need to manually add any route for an L2 connected IPs. It will start working once you remove the route.

Comment: btw, if it solves your problem can you up vote and accept the answer? thanks.

Comment: Sure !! i will test tormorow and reporte back

Comment: I can not vote up my reputation is low